# how to delete myself with reference

Tags: c++

```
void deleteElement(LinkedListElement<char> *&pending)
{
    if (pending->Next) {
        char value = pending->Next->Data;
        pending->Data = value;
        LinkedListElement<char> *temp = pending->Next;
        pending->Next = pending->Next->Next;
        delete temp;
    }else{
        pending = NULL;
        //pending =nullptr;
        delete pending;
    }
}
```

Simple delete node in C++
what i want to ask is in the else statement, if the linked list is end , so i can just delete myselft, i pass value by reference(&), but it does not work

```
void deleteElement(LinkedListElement<char> *&pending)
{
    if (pending->Next) {
        char value = pending->Next->Data;
        pending->Data = value;
        LinkedListElement<char> *temp = pending->Next;
        pending->Next = pending->Next->Next;
        delete temp;
    }else{
        delete pending;
        //pending = NULL;
    }
}
```

i try this way, but it always give me error:
malloc: *** error for object 0x100103b40: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
 delete pending;
 pending = NULL;
```

(**your version is the other way around**). Notice you're first setting the pointer to `NULL`, and after that deleting it, so you're effectively calling `delete` on a null pointer. Which is a no-op - memory is not released.

Comment: @ the error i put on the top, i edit the topic

Comment: @Hypnoz memory issues... impossible to debug without full code. You probably didn't allocate it with `new`, as the debugger says. Narrow it down.